# How to make it possible to add a group of fields indefinitely?

Tags: custom-fields, groups, civigrant, grant

In my country, when submitting grants, we fill in the calendar plan calendar plan. I implement this through a group of fields, but I need the user to be able to fill in this group once or an infinite number

Comment: Have you considered creating a new Activity Type for this - that way it can be done as often as you want

Comment: otherwise there is the 'multi record' custom field option